# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio sometimes Sees but other times Fails to See

Tags: database-administration, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-management-studio, sql-server-express

My computer has the following Software involved.

- Microsoft Windows 7
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Moreover, I have the following Drive partitions:

- C: drive
- D: drive
- E: drive

Therefore, when I created the Database Engine, I specify that the Instance Root Directory within a directory belonging to the D: drive which means that ldf and mdf files are placed the instance root directory within the D: drive.

However, there is a problem with the setup. If I restart my computer, sometimes the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio will see the Database Engine with the instance root directory within the D: drive but other times it won't see it. I keep restarting my computer to see if Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio sees the aforementioned Database Engine.

Why is it so unstable? Also, please tell me what steps I have to take in order to ensure Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio always sees the aforementioned Database Engine.

Comment: if you have correctly diagnosed the issue as access to the data and log files, then the issue is likely the order in which the disks are mounted, and the order in which the services start. Is your d driver connected internally or via USB? if so, try connecting it internally, and if not, perhaps try setting the SQL server services to start type Automatic (Delayed Start).

Answer (score 0):

@frank-Thomas  Thanks for your comment.
Here is what I had to check and ensure to resolve the problem[image]

[image]

Comment: yes.  if what you said about the data files being inaccessible is true, then the service crashed and stopped on start (at boot). perhaps "Automatic (Delayed Start)" will start late enough that your D drive is ready.